# "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman

I followed this microsoft document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow.I tried too many times ,but i still encounter this error.Which step did I do wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMRDc.png)

Comment: the link does not work. Maybe you could also enter the code you are testing, thanks.

Comment: You need to make a POST request. Not a GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is invalid. According to the picture you provided, you should be using [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code). I am trying to reproduce your problem:

[image]

The reason for the error is that you have used the wrong `code`. Please check your code to make sure it is correct.

[image]